# SELECT inside INSERT statement not working

Tags: mysql, select, insert

When I use this code, its working:

```
INSERT INTO `js_hdr`(`JO_NO`) SELECT MAX(`JO_NO`) + 1 from `js_hdr`
```

but when I add columns, its not working, like this:

```
INSERT INTO `js_hdr`(`TRAN_NO`,`JO_NO`) '1', SELECT MAX(`JO_NO`) + 1 from `js_hdr`
```

thank you in advance. I'm using Mysql

Comment: @sashkello: Sir it works when I switch the columns like this: INSERT INTO `js_hdr`(`TRAN_NO`,`JO_NO`)  SELECT MAX(`JO_NO`) + 1, 1 from `js_hdr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it by removing the `'1',` and put it in the `SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO `js_hdr`(`TRAN_NO`,`JO_NO`)
SELECT '1',MAX(`JO_NO`) + 1 from `js_hdr`
```

Comment: Yes! thank you sir, i did not know that I can do this kind of statement, it works for me :)